# Compile all .tex files to pdf in a new folder

Tags: python, file, directory

I have multiple folders with several `.tex` files stored in them.

I want to write a python script where it compiles all those `.tex` files (to pdf *only*) and store them in a new folder called `PDF Folder` with relevant sub folders.

So far I've been able to identify all the `.tex` files in those subfolders and how to compile it but it's very time consuming and inefficient as it still required a lot of manual input.

My script is as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
all_tex_files = []
for dirs,subdirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tex"):
            all_tex_files.append(os.path.join(file))

if not os.path.isdir('PDF Folder'):
   os.makedirs('PDF Folder')

for tex_files in all_tex_files:
    glob.iglob(str(tex_files))
    subprocess.run(['pdflatex', tex_files])
```

My folders are organised like this.

[image: Folder Organisation]

Desired result would look something like this.

```
\PDF Folder\Folder 1\Folder 1 File 1.pdf
\PDF Folder\Folder 1\Folder 1 File 2.pdf
...
\PDF Folder\Folder 2\Folder 2 File 1.pdf
\PDF Folder\Folder 2\Folder 2 File 2.pdf
```

Note* Folder 1,2 ... and .pdf file names are the original file names of the .tex file.

Update 1*

```
import os
import subprocess

path = os.getcwd()
all_tex_files = []
for dirs,subdirs,files in os.walk('.'):  
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tex"):
            all_tex_files.append(os.path.join(dirs,file))

if not os.path.isdir('PDF Folder'):  
   os.makedirs('PDF Folder')
   
for tex_files in all_tex_files:
    subprocess.run(['pdflatex',tex_files])
```

The above code now loops through all `.tex` files in the subfolders and compiles them in the same folder as the python script.

Comment: There is a least one error in your code what would prevent it from working. Also, what is currently "very time consuming" and requiring "a lot on manual input" about it?

Comment: Well at the moment this code`glob.iglob(str(tex_files))
    subprocess.run(['pdflatex', tex_files])` prompts me to enter the file names individually and i want it to automatically turn all those .tex files into pdf and store them in the pdf folder without me having to specificy which ones.

Comment: Those two lines of code would not do what you claim (i.e. prompt for file names). The first effectively does nothing and the second would attempt to run `pdflatex` and pass it a `.tex` file name as a separate process (which it will not find because the file name passed is relative, not absolute). Perhaps it is the `pdflatex` program that is prompting you to enter a valid file name each time it is invoked with a bogus one… Please verify that by replacing the `subprocess.run(['pdflatex', tex_files])` line with a `print('processing', tex_files)` statement and seeing what happens.

Comment: It does pick up the file names `processing Folder 1 File 1.tex
processing Folder 2 File 1.tex` It works fine when I put all the `.tex` files in the same folder as the python script.

Comment: It works fine when you put all the `.tex` files in the same folder as the script because of the error I mentioned in my original comment — the call to `os.path.join()` is wrong.

Comment: You are right! I changed it to `os.path.join(dirs+'\\'+file)` and worked fine. However, now I need to figure out how to remove all those other files (`.aux` and `.log`) that get created and then store them in the PDF folder.

Comment: The correct way to call it in this case would be `os.path.join(dirs, file)` - see the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Wanting to know how to get rid of all those other files is a completely different question from this one altogether.

Comment: Does the `pdflatex` program accept a command line argument specifying the path to where it is to place the PDF file it creates?

Comment: No. I don't think so.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdflatex) I found the `pdflatex` program accepts an `-output-directory` argument. If correct you should be able to control the destination of the PDF files created. If not, you will need to add code *after* the `subprocess.run()` that copies or moves the file created to the desired location.